# run a function in body of a component in react

Tags: reactjs

this is my code  and I want to change my code in a way that when the this.props.checkLogin is false it runs the this.props.loginEvent directly without a button. I don't know if it is possible or not.
do you have any Idea? :

```
import React from "react";
    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                        {
                            this.props.checkLogin ? (
                                <>
                                 <div> something </div>
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                <div>
                                    {
                                        <button onClick={this.props.loginEvent}>click</button>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            )

                        }

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it outside the return statement.

```
import React from "react";
render() {
    if(!this.props.checkLogin){
        this.props.loginEvent()
    }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                        {
                            this.props.checkLogin ? (
                                <>
                                 <div> something </div>
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                <div>
                                    {
                                        <button onClick={this.props.loginEvent}>click</button>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            )

                        }

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea but it shows this error : ```Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.```

Answer (score 0):

doing any logical job inside `render()` is not an appropriate approach for React. it'll check login status every time the component gets updated(re-rendered), even when `checkLogin` value is not modified.

```js
// inside component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (!props.checkLogin) props.loginEvent();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (!nextProps.checkLogin) this.props.loginEvent();
    return true
  }

  render() {
    const requireLogin = !this.props.checkLogin;
    return ( <div> {requireLogin && <button onClick={this.props.loginEvent}>login</button>} </div>);
  }

}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checkLogin: false };
  }
  loginEvent() {
    console.log('logging in');
    this.setState({ checkLogin: true });
  }
  render() {
    return <div> <MyComponent checkLogin={this.state.checkLogin}
    loginEvent={this.loginEvent.bind(this)}/></div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation but this is not what I actually want to do. your code will always run ```return ( <div> logged in ? {isLoggedIn} </div>);``` or in my code it will always show ```something``` but I don't want it. I want this: when the checkLogin is false run the loginEvent (and nothing else! actually in my code the loginEvent will open a drawer and show the drawer) and when the checkLogin is true show 'shomething' .

Comment: It's basically the same thing. just replace the `isLoggedIn` with your component. I've updated code to your liking. FYI, to isolate the auth function from component, you really should consider check login & try login from router because app will flicker for a moment while logging in. do the logical job at router is the only way to prevent show meaningless stuff.